# Is it possible to construct a Haar measure on a locally compact group assuming the existence of such a measure on compact groups?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

At first I thought that, once one proves the existence of a Haar measure on compact groups, it should be relatively straightforward to construct it on locally compact groups, by adequately piecing together Haar measures on compact neighbourhoods of points in a locally compact group.

However, I then realized that these neighbourhoods need not have a group structure, which means that I can't make direct use of the existence of a Haar measure on compact groups. So, I was wondering if there is a way around this that doesn't require a completely different approach. In other words, is there a way to use the existence of a Haar measure on compact groups to prove the existence of a Haar measure on locally compact groups?

If I think of the special case of $\mathbb{R}$ there seems to be no obvious way of doing this. Moreover, since no additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact, it doesn't seem possible to construct a Haar measure in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his book on "Topological groups and their applications" (in French), A. Weil did show that, for an *abelian* not-compact group $A$, there is a *discrete* subgroup $\Gamma$ such that the *group* $A/\Gamma$ is compact. This gives an invariant/Haar measure on $A$ by the functional
$$
\int_A f(a)\;da \;\;=\;\; \int_{A/\Gamma}\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma} f(a\gamma)\,d\dot{a}
$$
for compactly supported continuous $f$, with measure on the quotient given by $d\dot{a}$. Then the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem does give an actual measure $da$ on $A$.

Comment: Nitpicking: you don't need to assume $A$ is not-compact